# Flask is not able to read my environment variable

Tags: flask, web-applications, dotenv

I want to automatically import my FLASK_APP environment variable when running the Windows cmd.

I installed the python-dotenv, then created an .env file under my project main path.
However, I kept getting errors saying " Could not locate Flask application. You did not provide the FLASK_APP environment variable."

The following is the path I have for my project
[project Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cQ5C.png)

And my .env is saved under the same path "Flask Virtue Environment\env\Voting Platform\Voting_Platform"

my .env file has the following code 
FLASK_APP=runserver.py

Also I ran the following command to test if dotenv is able to locate my Environment File. I think it did find the file. (see below)
[dotenv test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9Hsq.png)

I am confused why the flask isn't able to read my .env file

Answer (score 0):

I never develop flask in windows, but you can read [this document](http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/configuration.html) to get clue for you problem.

Happy coding.